# Javascript continue on forEach

Tags: javascript

Is it impossible to use 'continue' with forEach ?  Following gives errors.

```
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
function myFunction() {
  numbers.forEach(function(val){ 
   if(index==2){
      continue;
    }
    alert('val: '+val);
  }); 
}
```

Is there any other work around to use continue?

Comment: Nowadays, you can (and I'd argue "should") use `for..of` rather than `forEach`. This will be compatible with `continue` and `break`. Index can also be retrieved via `array#entries()`. Example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it impossible to use 'continue' with forEach ?

Yes.

> Is there any other work around to use continue?

Use `return` to exit a function immediately.

Comment: Might be useful to point out that `return` in the closure does not stop further iteration. If iteration needs to be stopped in a `forEach` an exception needs to be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

```
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
function myFunction() {
  numbers.forEach(function(val, index){ 
    if(index!=2)
      alert('val: '+val);
});
```